# Issue to convert the ssl certificates from pfx to peem with openssl

Tags: openssl

when i try to convert the .pfx certifates to .pem to import to ACM, i get this error

**Error outputting keys and certificates
8C2B0000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:346:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()**

the command i run

**openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -out filename.pem**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the command used to work in previous OpenSSL versions, try the following:

Ensure you have the legacy library (file named legacy*.<os_lib_ext>, e.g. legacy-x64.dll). Instead of configuring environment variables it may be easier to just copy the library as legacy.<os_lib_ext> (e.g. legacy.dll) in both the libraries path and the path containing openssl executable.

Then add -legacy -provider-path "/path/to/legacy_library/dir" -provider default:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in filename.pfx -out filename.pem -legacy -provider-path "/path/to/legacy_library/dir" -provider default
```

Comment: Nice one. In my case it was enough to add the `-legacy` argument.

Comment: Thank you very much Jon for the answer. It really helped me a lot since I was working on upgrading my OPENSSL from 1.1.x to 3.1.1 and was stuck while converting P12 files to KEY and CRT.  Can using legacy encryption lead to any vulnerability ?

Comment: You won't believe how much I tried to follow the answers from chatgpt. the -legacy solved so easily that i'm happily frustrated.