# Issues while migrating from OpenSSL 1.1.x to OpenSSL 3.1.1(creating .crt and .key files from a .p12 file)

Tags: java, ssl, java-8, openssl, self-signed

I am creating self signed certificates for my Java Web Application. My application uses Apache Tomcat and Apache HTTPD proxy. I was using OPENSSL 1.1.1 and Java keytool till now for self signed certificates and it works perfectly fine. But now I need to move to OpenSSL 3.1.1 and am facing issues.

Step1: Create a keystore

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias keystore -keyalg RSA -keystore C:\SSL\PVIStore -keysize 2048
```

Step2: Import keystore generated in step#1 to a .p12 file

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\SSL\PVIStore -destkeystore C:\SSL\PVIStore.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

Step3: Get .crt file from file generated in step#2 using openssl 3.1.1

```
openssl pkcs12 -in C:\PVIStore.p12 -nokeys -out C:\SSL\PVIStore.crt
```

Step4: Get .key file from the file generated in step#2 using openssl 3.1.1

```
openssl pkcs12 -in C:\SSL\PVIStore.p12 -nocerts -nodes -out C:\SSL\PVIStore.key
```

Step #3 and Step #4 work perfectly fine in openssl 1.1.x but when using with openssl 3.1.1 I am getting below error:-

**Error outputting keys and certificates
94210000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto\evp\evp_fetch.c:341:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()**

Note: I got a workaround to work for me by following another [stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69361375/issue-to-convert-the-ssl-certificates-from-pfx-to-peem-with-openssl/71039379#71039379), but I do not want to use the legacy switch to move ahead.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: 40-bit RC2 is super weak as a cipher, I'd switch to grown up ciphers instead of trying to make legacy work. "A typical home computer in 2004 could brute-force a 40-bit key in a little under two weeks".

Comment: @Kayman RC2-40 is broken, but it has been used in PFX/PKCS12 for decades _only for certificates_ which don't need to be confidential at all; they are _designed_ to be public, and no one knows how this silly tradition of 'masking' them with RC2-40 started except that probably, as usual, it's Microsoft's fault. (In contrast we DO know Sun was to blame for the lousy encryption used in JKS for privatekeys where it _does_ matter :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. You can change your OpenSSL config file to load the legacy provider (*in addition* to the default one); this can be either the compiled-in file (depends on your system/environment but typically something like `/etc/pki/openssl.conf` or `/usr/share/openssl.conf`) or your own file set with an env var, see [How to enable the OpenSSL 3.0 legacy provider Github Actions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74545780/how-to-enable-the-openssl-3-0-legacy-provider-github-actions) .

   This still uses the legacy *algorithm* just not the `-legacy` *option*; I don't know if this satisfies your objection.
2. If you want to stop using the old algorithm, use `keytool` from Java [8u301 11.0.12 or 16 up](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8153005) -- or manually modify the settings in `java.security` *or* set the equivalent system properties in [12 through 15](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8076190) but those are all end-of-life now so that's probably a bad idea.
3. Or going further afield, you can use OpenSSL to create your key and self-signed cert in the first place, not Java `keytool`. With OpenSSL 3.0.0 up, `openssl pkcs12 -export` will use only new encryption (PBES2/AES) which both OpenSSL 3.x and 1.x will read, however some versions of *Java* (and specifically some updates of Java 8) cannot read these files either because of PBES2 in general, PBES2 with AES, or PBMAC-SHA256; there are numerous Qs about these here and on security.SX superuser serverfault.

   There are several variations with `openssl` commandline: you can create the key separately with `genrsa` or `genpkey`, then a CSR with `req -new`, then a cert with `x509 -req -signkey`. You can combine the first step into the second using `-newkey [-keyout] [-nodes]`, and the third step into the second using `-x509` (i.e. an option not a subcommand). And lots of Qs about all of them.

Also FYI in Java 9 up the default keystore type is PKCS12, so if `-genkey[pair]` creates a new keystore (i.e. doesn't update an existing JKS) that keystore is already PKCS12 and doesn't need to be converted with `-importkeystore`. In Java 8 you can change the default type to PKCS12 in `java.security` if you want.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave for your inputs. I tried option of creating the certificates first using option 3 and then converting them to P12 and JKS files and it worked perfectly fine for me. Thank you very much again for saving my day. Used OpenSSL 3.1.1 and JDK 8u_371

Answer (score 0):

Add the `-legacy` option to your OpenSSL `pkcs12` command line.

See the man page which says this:

> When encountering problems loading legacy PKCS#12 files that involve, for example, RC2-40-CBC, try using the -legacy option and, if needed, the -provider-path option.

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html

Comment: Thanks for your input Matt, I have already tried and it works, but do we have any other way we can create crt and key files from the keystore file generated in step#1. I am using p12 file, since openssl I assume does not recognize the keystore file.

Comment: I don't know the java side of things so can't advise there. Ideally you would create p12 files that don't use the legacy algs. OpenSSL cannot read keystore files directly.