Import Java created .p12 into macos keychain fails with invalid password
I have a Java application which creates .p12 files (with Bouncycastle (BC)).  I'm not able to import the .p12 file created via Java into macOS (macos 11) keychain:
security import mycert-personauth.p12 -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db

This prompts for the password and when I enter it fails "Sorry, you entered an invalid password".  If I use the same password with openssl to view the file it works fine:
openssl pkcs12 -in mycert-personauth.p12 -info  -nokeys -passin pass:$pw

If I create a p12 from the same certs in mycert-personauth.p12 it works.
openssl pkcs12 -export -out ~/test1.pfx -inkey cert/mytest-personauth.key -in cert/mytest-personauth.crt -certfile ca/ca-trust.crt
security import ~/test1.pfx -k ~/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db 
[ GUI prompt for password here ]
1 identity imported.
2 certificates imported.

Here is the non-working myc ert-personauth.p12 as reported by openssl (run on Linux with openssl 3.0.11):
MAC: sha256, Iteration 10000
MAC length: 32, salt length: 20
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 10000, PRF hmacWithSHA256
PKCS7 Encrypted data: PBES2, PBKDF2, AES-256-CBC, Iteration 10000, PRF hmacWithSHA256
Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
friendlyName: certandkey
localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 37 31 37 37 31 30 30 32 33 39 38 31
subject=/DC=com/DC=contoso/CN=Users/CN=David Bowie
issuer=/DC=com/DC=contoso/CN=Contoso Issuing CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: CN=Contoso Issuing CA,DC=contoso,DC=com
subject=/DC=com/DC=contoso/CN=Contoso Issuing CA
issuer=/CN=Contoso Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: CN=Contoso Root CA
subject=/CN=Contoso Root CA
issuer=/CN=Contoso Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Here is the working test1.p12 that imports successfully (openssl run on macos):
MAC Iteration 2048
MAC verified OK

PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048

Certificate bag
Bag Attributes
    localKeyID: F8 AB 55 96 23 95 4F 41 50 87 DB 98 41 DE 3A 78 50 66 2B 6D 
subject=/DC=com/DC=contoso/CN=Users/CN=David Bowie
issuer=/DC=com/DC=contoso/CN=Contoso Issuing CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Certificate bag
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=/DC=com/DC=contoso/CN=Contoso Issuing CA
issuer=/CN=Contoso Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Certificate bag
Bag Attributes: <No Attributes>
subject=/CN=Contoso Root CA
issuer=/CN=Contoso Root CA
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
PKCS7 Data
Shrouded Keybag: pbeWithSHA1And3-KeyTripleDES-CBC, Iteration 2048 

So there must be some problem in our Java code. Here is the greatly simplified Java code:
// keyPassword is set to same value as the keystore password
public void setPrivateKey(PrivateKey key, String alias, String keyPassword, java.security.cert.Certificate[] chain) {
   ...
   KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
   // chain[0] is subject cert and chain[0-N] is ca trust
   keyStore.setKeyEntry(alias, key, keyPassword.toCharArray(), chain);
   }

EDIT 1
Copied certs to linux with openssl 3.0.11.  Updated output above for mytest-personauth.p12, but test1.pfx fails to be handled by openssl on linux (works on macos openssl):
$ openssl pkcs12 -in test1.pfx -info -nokeys -passin pass:'test'
MAC: sha1, Iteration 2048
MAC length: 20, salt length: 8
PKCS7 Encrypted data: pbeWithSHA1And40BitRC2-CBC, Iteration 2048
Error outputting keys and certificates
100000000A000000:error:0308010C:digital envelope routines:inner_evp_generic_fetch:unsupported:crypto/evp/evp_fetch.c:373:Global default library context, Algorithm (RC2-40-CBC : 0), Properties ()


What openssl is this? Your first display "Here is the non-working ... reported by openssl" doesn't show the encryption details for "PKCS7 Encrypted data:" and "Shrouded Keybag:" which occurs in real OpenSSL 1.0.0 and 1.0.1 (obsolete for a decade) when confronted with PBES2 encryption used by recent Java versions (since about 2020) and maybe Bouncy (I can't easily check, and your code doesn't clearly show it being used anyway) but AIUI MacOS supplies LibreSSL instead -- which originally forked from OpenSSL 1.0.1 and I don't know if or how this area has changed since. ...

... In any case if Keychain also has problems with PBES2 that would explain your first file failing and second file working (because it isn't PBES2). Or the problem might be more specific to something like PBES2-with-SHA2 or even PBMAC-with-SHA2 used by recent Java and also current OpenSSL (3.0 up) by default.

The openssl output in my original post was from openssl on macos.  Copied certs to linux box with openssl 3.0.11 and got more details on one cert, but it failed to parse the test1.pfx.  See edits above.

Your working file was already known to use sha1+rc2-40 and sha1+3des (as most things did before about 2020) and rc2-40 is no longer supported by default in OpenSSL 3.0 up so there you must specify -legacy; see https://stackoverflow.com/q/69361375 and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/77051702 . Your nonworking file is now confirmed as using PBES2-with-SHA2 and PBMAC-with-SHA2, but as I said I don't know if these are problems for Keychain -- and it may well depend on version; your MacOS 11 is from 2020, before using PBES2 or PBMAC-SHA2 in PKCS12 became common.

I get the same results when I import on macos 14.5 :(

Figured out the problem.  I was using:
KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")

which creates a KeyStore using the builtin Java provider.  If I use the BC provider everything works fine:
KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12", "BC")
Simple solution which should have been more obvious. :(
